# Calculating the percentage of overlap between polytopes (n-dimensions)

Tags: r, geometry

I have to figure out the percentage of overlap between polytopes in n-dimensional spaces, where my only available source of reference is a set of randomly sampled points within those polytopes.

Assume that the following two R objects are two sets of randomly sampled points from two different polytopes in 5 dimensions:

```r
one <- matrix(runif(5000, min = 0, max = 5), ncol = 5) 
two <- matrix(runif(5000, min = 0, max = 4), ncol = 5)
```

In this example, I selected a smaller range for the second object, so we know that there should be less than 10% overlap. Let me know if I am wrong.

EDIT:
Just to make it really clear, the question is what is the percentage of overlap between those two objects?

I need a method that generalizes to n-dimensional spaces.

This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29702796/how-to-compute-percentage-of-overlap-in-r) is somewhat similar to what I am trying to do, but I didn't manage to get it to work.

Comment: Have you looked at R pkg [volesti](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/volesti/index.html), though I'm probably misinterpreting % overlap as intersection.

Comment: Not yet, but thank you very much, I will have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the most straightforward way is to use the [hypervolume](https://cran.r-project.org/package=hypervolume) package.

```r
library(hypervolume)
one <- hypervolume(matrix(runif(5000, min = 0, max = 5), ncol = 5))
two <- hypervolume(matrix(runif(5000, min = 0, max = 4), ncol = 5))

three = hypervolume_set(one, two, check.memory=FALSE)
get_volume(three)
```

This will get you the volume.

```
hypervolume_overlap_statistics(three)
```

This function will output four different metrics, one if which is the Jaccard Similarity Index.
The [Jaccard Similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) is the proportion of overlap between the two sample sets (the intersection divided by the union).

### Alternatives

[Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/794450/chris) suggested volesti as an alternative. Another alternative would be the geometry package.

They do not calculate the proportion straight away. Here you need to find the intersection (e.g. `intersectn` in `geometry`, `VpolytopeIntersection` in volesti), then calculate the volume for the polytopes separately and also their intersection, then you need to divide the volume of the intersection with the sum of the volumes for the two polytopes.

Here, they are also using a different method to calculate the volume and it might be more appropriate for you if you are trying to construct convex hulls in an n-dimensional space. For me, hypervolume is a better solution, because I am doing something more akin to Hutchinson’s n-dimensional hypervolume concept from ecology and evolutionary biology.

Comment: hypervolume cuts right to the chase. You might change your link to `index.html` rather than `hypervolumn.pdf`. Good Q/A.

Comment: Thanks! I change it to the canonical form provided by CRAN.